# How to access reverse relationship in django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models one for User and another for storing CustomerInfo(user of type customer).

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """ 
    This is a class for user table which overrides functionalities of default django user model.
      
    Attributes: 
        name (CharField): Name of a user.
        email (EmailField): Email address of a user. 
        mobile (CharField): Phone number of a user.
        date_joined (CharField): When a user was added.
        last_login (CharField): Last login date time of a user.
        is_admin (CharField): If user is a admin or not.
        is_active (CharField): If user is active or not.
        is_staff (CharField): If user is staff or not.
        is_superuser (CharField): If user is a superuser or not.
        role (OneToOneField): One to one relationship with role table.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r"^\d{10,14}$",
                message="Phone number must be entered in format: '+999999999'. Up to 14 digits allowed.",
            )
        ],
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
    )
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    drivers = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", through="DispatcherDriver", symmetrical=False
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "mobile"

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "name"]

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


class CustomerInfo(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name="customer_info"
    )
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "customer_info"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

CustomerInfo model has OneToOneField mentioned in the model. How can I access CustomerInfo of a User model using reverse relationship?

Comment: Where are you trying to use it? Share the viewset as well and your attempt too.

Comment: @Neeraj I am trying to access this using a another model which has User model as foreign key

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you has User's instance `user` then you can fetch `customer_info` as

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    customer_info = user.customer_info
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("There is no customer info here.")
```

Reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: It's not necessary to import `ObjectDoesNotExist`, because the model objects have their ow method. in this case, User.DoesNotExist

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
myuser = User.objects.create(email="..", name="..", password="1223")

profile = CustomerInfo.objects.create(customer=myuser)

company_name = myuser.customer_info.company_name
```

Comment: When I try to access it like this I get this error "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customer_info"

Comment: Apparently you haven't created `customer_info` for this particular user. Try `CustomerInfo.objects.filter(customer=user).exists()` and see for yourself.

Comment: Edited answer is now available